# Visual Studio Emulator for Android no upload my project to the emulator

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation

I'm starting to program Android app using Visual Studio 2015 (C#). I installed Xamarin, Android SDK and Visual Studio Emulator for Android. Starting deploy and emulator going well, but i can't find my project(application) on Virtual Machine.
When i unlock phone(virtual machine) i can't find my app (menu etc.).

The picture [visual studio screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pImF1.jpg)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  App2 -> C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Basic\App2\App2\bin\Debug\App2.dll
2>Starting deploy 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
2>Starting emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
2>Validating emulator arguments...
2>Determining if emulator is already running...
2>Preparing virtual machine...
2>Launching emulator...
2>Emulator launched successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I hope with this list you solve your problem, exist many reasons that you are having this problem try this different options.

1) Run the Visual Studio 2015 run as administrator.

2) Open the log and watch the last errors.

[image]

3) In this link  you can watch the correct installation of the VS Android Emulator [Visual Studio Emulator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/)

4) Check you have installed que correct SDK version.

Comment: I have many Error logs(Xamarin Open Logs...). The most common is:

     "GetMonodroidVersion didn't match: 
    Cannot determine the text encoding for the assembly location: E:\Pliki programów (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mandroid-win.exe
    Please add the correct encoding to MONO_EXTERNAL_ENCODINGS and try again."

Also i can find many NullReferenceException, System.Net.Sockets.SocketException. 
The project does not have any error/warning in Visual Studio.

Comment: You are sure that you have installed the SDK version for Android 4.4  try install other device and the corresponding SDK version and try again

Answer (score 0):

Like @MarcosJoséPérezPérez said, there are many reason this could be happening and looking at logs and your Visual Studio Output window may help.

A few steps you can try, a combination of these almost always works for me but I have not personally tried the Visual Studio Android Emulator yet:

1. Uninstall the app from the emulator
2. In the emulator, go to Settings -> App -> look for an entry that is the same name as your **Package name** (which is listed in your Android project properties under **Android Manifest**), if you see it, uninstall that also
3. In Visual Studio open your **Configuration Manager** (located at the bottom of the Visual Studio **Build** menu) and make sure that the **Build** and **Deploy** boxes are checked for your Android project.
4. Delete all `bin/` and `obj/` folders in your Android project directory (also delete them in your shared project directory if you have one).
5. Open your Android Project Properties, head to **Android Options** -> **Advanced** and make sure at least the `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` architectures are checked.
6. Rebuild project

Comment: I find "solution" to my issue. I using Android Emulator instead Visual Studio Emulator for Android. 
I'm done all your points. Unfortunately i have problem with 2 point. In Settings -> App (emulator) i can't find my application.